# Unable to require RubyGems

Tags: ruby, rubygems, require

I have RubyGems version 1.8.5 and Ruby version 1.8.7. My problem is that even after installing gems I am not able to `require` it. On the command line typing `gem list --local` gives:

```
bundler (1.0.15)
hpricot (0.8.4)
json (1.5.1)
redcarpet (1.17.1)
```

But this does not help.

```
begin
    require 'bundler'
    rescue LoadError => boom
        warn "Bundler not found"
    exit 0
end
# I get Bundler not found
```

I am running Ubuntu Natty 32-bit

UPDATE: After requiring RubyGems in `irb` I get a much informable error i.e.

```
LoadError: no such file to load -- bundler
from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from (irb):3
from :0
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you are requiring rubygems before you require bundler anywhere.

Comment: @Jergason I actually tried to clone official github-services and run the commands they mentioned in the README. From there I got the error that Bundler was not installed when I had installed it. Their code run a whole website so probably the problem is with my system.

Comment: @Jergason You advice helped and now I am getting much better error message. I have updated the question with that

Answer (score 2):

Bundler does not provide `bundler` as a file you require directly. Instead you have to require `bundler/setup`, as shown in the documentation:

http://gembundler.com/

```
require "rubygems"
require "bundler/setup"

# require your gems as usual
require "nokogiri"
```

Also, on Ruby 1.8.7, you **still need** to `require 'rubygems'`

Hope that helps

Comment: Sorry, it didn't help. I again got the error I mentioned in the question

Comment: Please see the update, with Ruby 1.8.7, you still need require "rubygems", even that is installed with Ruby, you still need to perform the require.

Comment: I required "rubygems" and still nothing happened. It seems to me maybe that ruby is searching the wrong path or gems are being installed at wrong place. But I don't know how to correct that.

Comment: Please do the following: check `gem env` where it stored the gems and also check `gem list -d` where the gems are really stored. Ubuntu is know for being problematic on this topic.

Comment: Thanks, it solved the issue. Actually, I had two versions of ruby installed on my computer. 1.8.7 and 1.9.1. And gem path could be searched only by 1.9.1 version but I was using 1.8.7 for it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you've loaded rubygems? What happens when you enter an `irb` session and type `require 'rubygems'`?

Comment: @Ankit did you have the `require 'rubygems'` line that @Kamiel_Wanrooij pointed to you?